# Invariance of Gaussian under rotation

Tags: random-matrices, gaussian

I am reading a paper, it stated the following lemma and the proof.

**Lemma** Let $z \in R^{n}$ be a random vector with i.i.d, $\mathcal{N}(0,v^2)$ entries and let $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a linear operator with full row rank. Then for any constant vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ the distribution of $z$ conditioned on $Dz = b$ sastifies 
$$ z |_{Dz =b} \stackrel{d}{=} D^*(DD^*)^{-1}b + P_{\{Dz = 0\}}(\tilde{z})$$ where $P_{\{Dz = 0\}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\{Dz = 0\}$ and $\tilde{z}$ is a random vector of i.i.d $\mathcal{N}(0,v^2)$.

With $X|_{\sigma} \stackrel{d}{=} Y$ means $X$ is distributed as (or equal in distribution to) $Y$ conditional on $\sigma$.

**Proof** The result is trivial if $D = \{I_{m \times m} | 0_{ m \times (n-m)}\}$. For general $D$, it follows by invariance of the Gaussian distribution under rotations.

The author said that it is a well-known formula, I did search on the Internet but I can't find any reference for this result. Can anyone explain for me the invariance of Gaussian distribution under rotation and why we can find the conditional distribution of $z$ on $\{Dz = b\}$ by the orthogonal projection of $\tilde{z}$ onto $\{Dz = 0\}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: invariance under rotation: $P(z)=\exp[-(v^2/2) z^T I z]=P(Oz)$ for any orthogonal $O$, since $O^T O=I$.

Comment: I always liked Rosenthal's book for the calculus of Gaussian vectors. It is very expressive with regards to that. The book is available for free here: http://probability.ca/jeff/probstatbook.html